# JS - Chrome Extension - addEventListener('copy') not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to develop a chrome extension however while trying to add an EventListener on the copy action it does not work (though supported by the browser because it is working on fiddle).

here are my different files.

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Bla",
  "description": "bla",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "camera.png",
    "default_title": "bla"
  },

  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },

  "content_scripts" : [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["oncopy.js"]
    }
  ],

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/",
    "clipboardRead",
    "clipboardWrite"
  ]
}
```

oncopy.js

```
document.addEventListener("copy", function() {
    alert('copied')
    }, true);
```

The alert never pops up.

I also tried with a similar code inside a background.js file called by background.html but didn't work either... Any ideas ?

Comment: Spec [says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/copy) the target should be either the element itself or `document.body`, not just `document`.

Comment: example in spec is also with document.addEventListener: document.addEventListener('copy', function(e){
    e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', 'Hello, world!');
    e.clipboardData.setData('text/html', '<b>Hello, world!</b>');
    e.preventDefault(); // We want our data, not data from any selection, to be written to the clipboard
});

Comment: Yeah, it works on document in Chrome so MDN is incorrect there. Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: no and actually if I put the script in the background.js and open the chrome-extension://extension-id/background.html page (to access my extension hiden page directly) it is working. it really feels like the script does not affect the pages open but only the hidden "background.html" page.

Comment: Did you reload the page after installing/reloading the extension? Automatic injection of content scripts occurs only on page (re)load.

Comment: Yep, reloaded, restarted chrome even. I however dont find in the extensions documentation that this type of eventListener are blocked.
putting window instead of document leads to exactly same result (works if I reach the extension page but doesnt work in the "hiden" extenstion mode)

Comment: I can't reproduce. Your code is correct and works here.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(evt) {
   if (evt.target.readyState === "complete") {
     document.addEventListener("copy", function() {
      alert('copied')
     }, true);
   } 
}, false);
```

Comment: Unfortunately not working, feels like it's the fact that it is in the extensions that blocks it.

Comment: You can debug the extensions individually, did  you find any errors there?

Comment: Why would you think this would help?  The event listener is being placed on the `document`. The `document` node is not going to change between whenever the content script is run and when the `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired. In fact, this might result in the code not running at all. The content script is currently being `run_at` the default `document_idle`. this means that it *might* be injected after `window.onload`, which fires *after* `DOMContentLoaded`. Thus, this makes it such that, under some conditions, the `document.addListener` code will never run.

Comment: Thanks @Makyen for pointing out. I modified the above code to look for `readystatechange` instead of `DOMContentloaded`

Comment: You missed the fact that all `readystatechange` events may have already fired. In other words, the code may still not run. If you are going to delay the code execution, a useless thing to do in this case, you need to check the [`document.readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) prior to adding a listener for `readystatechange` events. If it is already `complete`, then you need to directly execute the code, if not, *then* you can add the `readystatechange` listener. This implies that the desired code needs to be in a named function, not anonymous.